# How does my resting heart rate influence my target heart rate?

Tags: target-heart-rate

My target heart rate for endurance training based on my age is about 135 beats per minute. Do I have to take into account, that I have a low resting heart rate or is that irrelevant. My resting heart rate is only 45 beats per minutes. Does this also lower my target heart rate?

Comment: how did you come up with 135 for your age?

Comment: If you really want to know YOUR specific threshold/zones for training, you'll want to get a lactic threshold test done.  Any other method/formula (except field testing) is slightly better than guessing.

Comment: @Ryan: From the first diagram in this thread - http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/how-do-i-workout-my-heart-rate-zones-for-training

I am currently 30 years old.

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  Charts like those are estimates at best.  It's enough to get you started, but if you are training for an endurance event, I'd go a different route.

Comment: These links may provide some info http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/272/is-there-a-definitive-way-to-calculate-a-target-heart-rate-for-a-cardiovascular-w  http://www.thewalkingsite.com/thr.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far, I got everything I needed to know. Lactic threshold test would be too much for me, because I don't train for a high class endurance event and a rough estimate is good enough right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Karvonen Formula](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Exercise-Target-Heart-Rate.html#Karvonen-Formula) shows you how to calculate your target heart rate taking into consideration your resting heart rate and your heart rate reserve.

Karvonen Formula: (MHR - RHR) x *_*% + RHR = THR

[MHR](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Exercise-Target-Heart-Rate.html#Maximum-Heart-Rate) is your maximum heart rate and is calculated by: 
MHR = 206.9 - (0.67 x age)    (This a newer formula than the old 220 - age).

RHR is your resting heart rate.

THR is your target heart rate.

Comment: This would mean a THR of 144,26 for me. Sounds reasonable and would fit into the diagram in http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/how-do-i-workout-my-heart-rate-zones-for-training for my age.